# DFT Vs DCT - spectrum differences

Tags: fourier-analysis

When you are transforming a signal in to a frequency domain using both DFT and DCT, say for a function sin(x), how the spectrum will be? will both frequency values (of DCT and DFT) same? Can anyone explain the values of the frequencies for the function sin(x) (obviously the frequency should be 1/2π)